# How to override local User Secrets and appsettings.json with Azure Container App's Secrets?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, azure-container-instances, azure-container-apps, azure-secrets

I have an **appsettings.json** in my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API and a **secrets.json** I use for development connection strings, like below:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings:MainDatabase": "CONNECTION STRING HERE"
}
```

After publishing my API as an **Azure Container App**, how can I **override** these **connection strings** from Azure?

I see the "Secrets" settings to configure a KeyVault, but **how can I link** those secrets to the User Secrets/appsettings used by my Web Api?

Comment: have you check this article, it explain how secrets can be bound to env variables:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/manage-secrets?tabs=arm-template. /in you case you would have an env variable `ConnectionStrings:MainDatabase` that would referenced the related container app secret.

Answer (score 4):

After updating or changing the `User Secrets` we need to restart or recreate the revision.

[image]

***My Secrets:***
[image]

***Reading Secret Key:***

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
{ 
  ViewBag.MyKey= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mykey");
  return View();
}
```

Make sure the name of the key must be same as the local Secret name.

Even if you have `secrets` created in the `Secrets` section of the Azure Container App, you can see the `Environment variables` in `Container` Section is unavailable.

[image]

For the secrets to work, we need to map the secrets into the `Environment variables`.

- Click on  `Edit and deploy`

[image]

***Create new Revision***

Click on the `container image` => Create `Environment variables` with mapping to the existing secrets =>Save => Refresh

[image]

Every time you make changes to the `secrets` in portal, If you don`t have the revision we need to create it or restart the existing Revision.

Use the below command to restart the revision.

```cs
az containerapp revision restart --resource-group "yourRG" --name "containerappname" --revision "revisionname"
```

[image]